# Did Best Jeanist die after All for One attack?

Tags: my-hero-academia

After this attack,

[image]

I thought Best Jeanist have died, and it's hard to imagine how could he have survived that attack and that hole in the stomach, but later Kamui Woods recovers his body along with Mt Lady. It doesnt make much sense to recover a dead body in the middle of a fierce battle, so, what happened after it? Did Best Jeanist die after All for One attack or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Best Jeanist didn't die after All for one's attack. He is heavily injured, but still alive.
He won't be returning to action anytime soon though.